# Cannot form regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used the below regex expression to check alphabets, numbers, characters, + and -

```
if (/[^a-z0-9\-\+]+$/i.test(value)) 
        {
            alert ("Only alphabets and numbers are allowed.");
            return;
        }
```

This shows the message if any special characters is used. But one problem i am facing is if the value is a combination of special characters and alphabets or numbers then this condition does not satisfy. For example if the value is `%$2` then the condition does not return true and show the message. I want that if any special character is present then the condition should satisfy and show the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `$` anchor. Also the final `+` is not necessary in your case. The following checks whether the string contains any disallowed characters:

```
if (/[^a-z0-9\-\+]/i.test(value)) 
{
    alert ("Only alphabets and numbers are allowed.");
    return;
}
```

You could also invert the condition. (Use `*` or `+` depending on whether you allow empty string.) The following checks whether the whole string only contains the allowed characters:

```
if (!/^[a-z0-9\-\+]*$/i.test(value)) 
{
    alert ("Only alphabets and numbers are allowed.");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` Matches the end of string 
and `$` is not required in your case

`+` matches previous token one or more times ,

and it is also not required in your case

```
 if (/[^a-z0-9\-\+]/i.test(value)) 
    {
        alert ("Only alphabets and numbers are allowed.");
        return;
    }
```